# Snap (snapd) hello-world example not working (path not found?)

Tags: snap

I just tried to used [`snap`](https://snapcraft.io/) for the first time and followed the tutorial [Getting started | Snapcraft documentation](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/basic-snap-usage#2).

I installed the hello world example `sudo snap install hello` but the `hello` command is not found. I noticed that the command is in /snap/bin but it seems that it missed it's way to my PATH.

When I installed snap (`sudo apt install snapd`) I got some error message the first time, but on the 2nd try it worked. (Removing and installing snapd did also not help.)

Do I have to add the path manually?

Any idea?

Edit:

- the `shout` irc web app did work immediately

Comment: I know this question is old but are you sure the app is named `hello` instead of `hello-world`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you've just installed snapd, try starting a fresh terminal window to pick up the new `$PATH`. You'll only need to do this once.

If your shell doesn't read from `/etc/profile.d` you'll need to add `PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin` to your shell configuration (e.g. `~/.zshrc` for zsh)

Comment: Thanks opening a new terminal solved it .... one could think this was quite obvious ;-)
(However, the rocketchat -server is still not working, but I guess this is a different story / question)

Comment: Cool! I'd take the RocketChat question to their Stackoverflow tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rocket.chat

Comment: I also found the reason for rocket.chat - one of the required ports was already used on this machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing zsh then you can easily configure just open your terminal and type

```
sudo gedit /etc/zsh/zprofile
```

If you use vim, vscode or anything just add this instead of gedit. And then add these two lines.

```
emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'
emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh'
```

Then save it and close. Now time to restart your PC hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem still occurs with Ubuntu 18.04 with Wayland, zsh and snapd.
See posts #18 and #19 in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1640514 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

On debian 9, I had to add `/snap/bin` to the root PATH manually. Do the following:

In `/etc/login.defs`, you will find the following line:

```
ENV_SUPATH PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Add the path so that it will be:

```
ENV_SUPATH PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

Exit the session, and login again.