# Cannot find application after snap install

Tags: snap

I followed the [installation guide from snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-debian). My system cannot find the `hello-world` application:

```
$ sudo snap install hello-world
[sudo] password for gauthier: 
hello-world 6.4 from Canonical✓ installed
$ hello-world
bash: hello-world: command not found
```

How do I fix this?

Debian 10, but I guess the process is the same as Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snap (snapd) hello-world example not working (path not found?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917233/snap-snapd-hello-world-example-not-working-path-not-found)

Comment: @Kulfy it does, I didn't think to search with hello world specifically, since I had the problem with another application first. Silly of me. I still don't get why installing snap with apt couldn't make the update to PATH.

Comment: I assume APT is reluctant to modify `/etc/environment`, `*profile*` or the shell specific files. :)

Comment: Moreover, if that question does answer your question, you may consider closing your question as a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Kulfy Duplicates can be good? https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: Absolutely. I never suggested/asked to delete the Q&A. The main purpose of closing questions as duplicate is to link them.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, installing `snap` from `apt` does not add the correct path to `/etc/environment`, or `PATH`.

The snap applications are in `/snap/bin/`, so there is the string to somehow add to your `PATH`.

I feel that this should be automated, or at least pointed out to the user upon installation of `snap`. (Yes, I rebooted with no success.)

Comment: I just checked on my system and `/snap/bin` is in `PATH`. However, the snap application in question may not add it's executable to `/snap/bin`. I know little about snaps, but I guess it's up to application to do that.

Comment: It's in /snap/bin

Comment: @raj **I just checked on my system and `/snap/bin` is in `PATH`**: That's because you may be using Ubuntu but Gauthier is using Debian. And in Ubuntu Desktop, Snap is installed by default. **the snap application in question may not add it's executable to `/snap/bin`**: Well that would defy the whole purpose of package managers and "automated" installation. Usually binaries or symbolic link to binaries are in `*bin`.