# How to execute the `hello-world` snap on Ubuntu 20.10 successfully?

Tags: snap, 20.10, apparmor

I recently attempted to use a couple of snap packages on 20.10.  I had troubles with those.  So I am back to first principles.  As shown in this response:

- [How to use Snap Packages when $HOME is not /home/$USER?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040265/62638)

  `snap install hello-world`

  and add the output of the following commands:

  `SNAP_CONFINE_DEBUG=yes hello-world`

  `dmesg | grep DENIED`

Unfortunately the `hello-world` does not even work.  Outputs are at the end of the question.  My questions for Ask Ubuntu are simple:

- What other steps are required for a person to run snaps after the bind-mount step?
- Is there some misconfiguration in the console output that I can correct?
- Is this a bug, config error or user error?
- How can I ensure smooth snap execution "most of the time"?

Please read on for details...

After installing `hello-world`, I attempted to run it with the following outcome:

```
 hello-world
 cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_un1MrN//dev: No such file or directory
```

Also the: `SNAP_CONFINE_DEBUG=yes hello-world`, diagnostic resulted in the same kind of error:

```
     ;
     :
 cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_sJmTk8//dev: No such file or directory
```

However this directory exists -- The problem involves permissions.  YES directory exists.  NO I do not have access to the directory: `snap.rootfs_un1MrN/`, none whatsoever.  Clearly this directory is necessary to run `hello-world` ...

```
 ls -la  -d /tmp/snap*
 drwx------ 2 root will 4096 Jan 11 10:18 /tmp/snap.rootfs_sdo6fl/
 drwx------ 2 root will 4096 Jan 11 10:16 /tmp/snap.rootfs_sJmTk8/
 drwx------ 2 root will 4096 Jan 11 10:17 /tmp/snap.rootfs_un1MrN/
```

My login is `id=(will)` and `gid=(will)`.  It is my observation that I'd need group access to the directory for anything to work as it stands.  I doubt if this is what is indended. I don't think the double slash(`//`) makes any difference.  I wonder though if there is a missing text fragment.

Full disclosure I am running with my home directory `bind` mount-*ed* to `/home/will/` as:

```
 mount --bind /data/home/will  /home/will
```

To work past the snap home directory short-comings.  I am wondering if there is a chance for me to use snap packaged software in the future if the hello-world can't even get started.

Hoping for some ideas to move forward.  Unfortunately there are some useful looking tools I can't take advantage of because they only come as a snap at present.

## versions

```
 snap list hello-world; snap --version
 Name         Version  Rev  Tracking       Publisher   Notes
 hello-world  6.4      29   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
 
 snap    2.48+20.10
 snapd   2.48+20.10
 series  16
 ubuntu  20.10
 kernel  5.8.0-36-generic
```

## references

- [Snap (snapd) hello-world example not working (path not found?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917233/snap-snapd-hello-world-example-not-working-path-not-found)
- [How to use Snap Packages when $HOME is not /home/$USER?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040265/62638)

## output

**`sudo dmesg`** `| grep DENIED`

```
 [   34.324082] audit: type=1400 audit(1610318223.394:51): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" name="/proc/1040/attr/apparmor/current" pid=1040 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
 [ 2400.019690] audit: type=1400 audit(1610320590.299:57): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/fast/ubuntu/var/lib/snapd/cookie/snap.hello-world" pid=15128 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

**`SNAP_CONFINE_DEBUG`**`=yes hello-world`

```
  $ sudo snap install hello-world
 [sudo] password for will: 
 hello-world 6.4 from Canonical✓ installed
 
  $ SNAP_CONFINE_DEBUG=yes hello-world
 DEBUG: umask reset, old umask was   02
 DEBUG: security tag: snap.hello-world.hello-world
 DEBUG: executable:   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-exec
 DEBUG: confinement:  non-classic
 DEBUG: base snap:    core
 DEBUG: ruid: 1000, euid: 0, suid: 0
 DEBUG: rgid: 1000, egid: 1000, sgid: 1000
 DEBUG: apparmor label on snap-confine is: /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
 DEBUG: apparmor mode is: enforce
 DEBUG: creating lock directory /run/snapd/lock (if missing)
 DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
 DEBUG: opening lock directory /run/snapd/lock
 DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
 DEBUG: opening lock file: /run/snapd/lock/.lock
 DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
 DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
 DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
 DEBUG: acquiring exclusive lock (scope (global), uid 0)
 DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
 DEBUG: ensuring that snap mount directory is shared
 DEBUG: unsharing snap namespace directory
 DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
 DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
 DEBUG: releasing lock 5
 DEBUG: opened snap-update-ns executable as file descriptor 5
 DEBUG: opened snap-discard-ns executable as file descriptor 6
 DEBUG: creating lock directory /run/snapd/lock (if missing)
 DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
 DEBUG: opening lock directory /run/snapd/lock
 DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
 DEBUG: opening lock file: /run/snapd/lock/hello-world.lock
 DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:0 (change: yes)
 DEBUG: set_effective_identity uid:0 (change: no), gid:1000 (change: yes)
 DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds
 DEBUG: acquiring exclusive lock (scope hello-world, uid 0)
 DEBUG: sanity timeout reset and disabled
 DEBUG: initializing mount namespace: hello-world
 DEBUG: snappy_udev_init
 DEBUG: forked support process 15141
 DEBUG: unsharing the mount namespace (per-snap)
 DEBUG: changing apparmor hat to mount-namespace-capture-helper
 DEBUG: scratch directory for constructing namespace: /tmp/snap.rootfs_sJmTk8DEBUG: helper process waiting for command
 DEBUG: DEBUG: sanity timeout initialized and set for 30 seconds performing operation: (disabled) use debug build to see details
 DEBUG: performing operation: (disabled) use debug build to see details
 DEBUG: performing operation: (disabled) use debug build to see details
 DEBUG: performing operation: (disabled) use debug build to see details
 DEBUG: performing operation: (disabled) use debug build to see details
 DEBUG: performing operation: (disabled) use debug build to see details
 cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_sJmTk8//dev: No such file or directory
```